# Can not receive notification email from Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

After following the Documentation : SMTP settings | GitLab. We already can send a test email in the console of the Gitlab. But We still can not receive the Notification from our self-organized Gitlab server even the Notification level is already in Watch level.

What we need to do to receive the Notification from Gitlab?

Any reply would be appreciated

I think we already have a email server in our Gitlab ,but how to active it as our notification email server (send invitation Link or Notification)

Update

[enter image description here][1]

Here is my configuration, it can send and receive email via the console or mailbox , but when i want to create an new account in the gitlab, the new account's email can not receive the email automatically. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTJee.png

Comment: You're going to need to include more details including configuration details/excerpts, (sanitized) logs, and screenshots.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the remind,  I am already updated my configuration's Informaiton below.